# How can I use an enum in my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, enums

I have an enum in model:

```
Public Enum WhatStatus
    <Display(Name:="Full Status")>FullStatus = 0
    <Display(Name:="Half Status")>HalfStatus = 1
    <Display(Name:="Part Status")>PartStatus = 2
    <Display(Name:="Less Status")>LessStatus = 3
End Enum
```

I am using a

```
EnumDropDownListFor(function(model) 
model.Item(0).aCollection.Item(0).ClassThatUses.Item(0).WhatStatus. Mew Wotj{........})
```

I have `modelType as a.MyCollection(of b)`

As I am typing the parameter for the `enumDropDownListFor` intellisense has the correct path to get to enum.  but when I run the webpage it says that index is out of range.  It is referring to `ClassThatUses.Item(0)`. I am sure that `classThatUses` is empty but I need to capture the enum for the dropdown.

Comment: you want to set ClassThatUses.Item to WhatStatus?

Comment: Error indicates that WhatStatus is not a part of b but if I use ClassThatUseseItem.WhatStatus without the Item(0) I get the same error.  When I put Item(0) in -- out of range index.

Comment: my question is using enum for what?

Comment: Did you try a `Partial Class` of the model class and add the enum there?